# How to introduce weights for Jensen's inequality into $log\sum\sum$

Tags: probability, inequality, optimization, jensen-inequality

For log sum matrix function, I saw the example introducing the weight after sum regarding all matrices in summation for Jensen's inequality

\begin{align*}
f(W,H) &= \sum_{ij}[-V_{ij}log \sum_{k}W_{ik}H_{kj}]\\
&= \sum_{ij}[-V_{ij}log \sum_{k}\color{red}{\pi_{ijk}}\frac{W_{ik}H_{kj}}{\color{red}{\pi_{ijk}}} ]\\
&\leq \sum_{ij}[-V_{ij}\sum_{k}\color{red}{\pi_{ijk}}log \frac{W_{ik}H_{kj}}{\color{red}{\pi_{ijk}}}]
\end{align*}

where $V,W,H$ are matrix, and $\pi_{ijk} = \frac{W_{ik}H_{kj}}{\sum_{k}W_{ik}H_{kj}}$ and $\sum_{k}\pi_{ijk} = 1$

But if I have two sums after $-log$. For example

$$f(W,H,\sigma,\phi) = \sum_{ij}[-V_{ij}log \color{blue}{\sum_{l}}\sigma_{l}\color{blue}{\sum_{k}}\phi_{lk}W_{lik}H_{lkj}]$$

where $\sigma$ is vector and $\phi$ is matrix

I wonder where I should introduce the weight $\color{red}\pi$? Which dimensions do I have to concern about? 
Is it ok to concern only $l$ dimension like this following?;
$$f(W,H,\sigma,\phi) = \sum_{ij}[-V_{ij}log \sum_{l}\color{red}{\pi_{l}}\frac{\sigma_{l}}{\color{red}{\pi_{l}}}\sum_{k}\phi_{lk}W_{lik}H_{lkj} ]$$

where $\pi_{l} = \frac{\sigma_{l}}{\sum_{l}\sigma_{l}}$

or all the dimensions after sum should have individual weight;

$$f(W,H,\sigma,\phi) = \sum_{ij}[-V_{ij}log \sum_{l}\sigma_{l}\sum_{k}\color{red}{\pi_{lijk}}\frac{\phi_{lk}W_{lik}H_{lkj}}{\color{red}{\pi_{lijk}}}]$$

where $\pi_{lijk} = \frac{\sigma_{l}\phi_{lk}W_{ik}H_{kj}}{\sum_{l}\sigma_{l}\sum_{k}\phi_{lk}W_{ik}H_{kj}}$

Comment: Why do you make those equations so complicated? You do not need the outer sum and the last term at all. Jensen inequality was applied only to the $\log \sum$ expression.

Comment: @cheyp here is the example of Kullback-Leibler divergence. I would like to understand in this form as I want to apply Jensen’s inequality to the modified KL formula for biological research purpose later on. May you explain if I have two sums like the question shown, where weight should be apply?

Comment: It does not answer my question, you do not need so many unnecessary terms. Concerning your question, one can introduce the weights wherever you want, it amounts to which RHS you want to get.

Comment: @cheyp I understand that the last term is not related so I removed it. Thanks. But I am not sure why you said the outer sum is unnecessary? By the way, I simplified the question. As you said weights can be introduced anywhere, so both cases in the question work? Is the dimension of weights important here?